# Pass T as a parameter to to conditionally create Generic in Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am trying to conditionally create a Generic instance in Java where the type is passed as a parameter. Something like this:

```
private void doStuff(somethingThatDescribesWhatTShouldBeHere) {

   ArrayList<thetypeTthatwaspassedin> = new ArrayList<thetypeTthatwaspassedin>
   ... rest of logic
}
```

I cannot figure out for the life of me what the T parameter should look like without the `ArrayList<T>` screaming back to me.

The idea is if `T` is a string then an `ArrayList<String>` is instantiated .. if it is Foo then an `ArrayList<Foo>` is instantiated instead inside.

Please help

Comment: Note that there is no difference between instantiating a `ArrayList<Foo>` and instantiating a `ArrayList<String>`. Understand that before you continue.

Comment: yeah..but I don't know what the parameter should look like. if it is Class then the compiler screams. In example if I pass in String.class as a parameter Param then I cannot do ArrayList<Param>. it simply doesn't want to compile. I know what the type is before I call doStuff .. but not inside doStuff..that needs to be passed in as an argument. The actual use case is related to GSONRequest<T>. however the factory function that creates the GSONRequest<T> must take the T type as a parameter and then return GSONRequest<foo> GSONRequest<bar> etc..

Comment: How is the `ArrayList` being used? To @Sotirios' point, it could just be `ArrayList<Object>` without any further context. Based on what you've written, the method takes nothing else related to `T` and returns `void` so it doesn't make sense to worry about what `T` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just make `doStuff` generic :

```
// If you can, pass a parameter of type T :
private <T> void doStuff(T something) {

   ArrayList<T> = new ArrayList<T>();
   ... rest of logic
}
// so it can be called like that :  
YourType param = ...;
foo.doStuff(param);

// If you can't pass a parameter of type T, you'll have
// to explicitly tell the compiler which type to use :
foo.<YourType>doStuff();
```

Passing `Class<T>` as hinted by Stijn Geukens is also a common way of avoiding the ugly, latter syntax if you don't need to pass an actual object.

Comment: The last example, `foo.<YourType>doStuff()`, shows that it's futile to even have `T` at all. It's a valid answer to a question that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Paul Bellora I agree, a more complete answer would explain this futility, but hey, I wouldn't know where to stop... If you begin to explain that, you'll have to explain type erasure, then explain why and when it's still valid to use generics (because, well, the OP would wonder), for which you may need to explain type specifications, maybe wildcards too, and... Well, you get the point. Feel free to edit my answer with what you think would be useful though.

Answer (score 2):

your method needs to be generic; e.g.:

```
class Ideone
{

    public <T> void test (Class<T> c) {
        List<T> t = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: both answers great. That's all I needed experts. I am transitioning from Java to .NET and it is a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: Generics can be very confusing; even for 'experts'.

Comment: Tell me about it. Especially when dealing with Android. Half of the Java libraries are simply missing.

Comment: Note that `Class<T> c` is unused and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two generic examples, one using static access:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Utility
{
    /**
     * Returns an empty mutable non-concurrent list, likely
     * java.util.ArrayList.
     *
     * @param <T> requested type for container
     *
     * @return  mutable non-concurrent list
     **/
    public static <T> List<T> newMutableList()
    {
        return (new ArrayList<T>());
    }
}


public class Utility2<T>
{
    /**
     * Returns an empty mutable non-concurrent list, likely
     * java.util.ArrayList.
     *
     * @param <T> requested type for container
     *
     * @return  mutable non-concurrent list
     **/
    public List<T> newMutableList()
    {
        return (new ArrayList<T>());
    }
}
```